# Im using php version 5.2. The script is working in 000webhost, but when i use yahoo web host it doesnt work

Tags: php, phpmailer

Can someone help why my script is not working in yahoo web host, but it is working in 000webhost. Im using phpmailer5.2 and Phpversion 5.2.12

The error is Connection failed. Error #2: stream_socket_client() [function.stream-socket-client]: unable to connect to smtp.gmail.com:587 (No route to host) [/products/phpmailer/class.smtp.php line 304]
2018-12-06 03:50:16 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: No route to host (65)
SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

```
<?php
$result="";
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
require_once ('phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');
$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host='smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->Port=587;
$mail->SMTPAuth=true;
$mail->SMTPSecure='tls';
$mail->Username='sample@gmail.com';
$mail->Password='';

$mail->setFrom($_POST['email'],$_POST['name']);
$mail->addAddress('');
$mail->addAddress('');
$mail->addAddress('');
$mail->addReplyTo($_POST['email'],$_POST['name']);

$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->Subject='Form Submission: '.$_POST['subject'];
$mail->Body='<h1 align=center>Name: '.$_POST['name'].'<br>Email: ' .$_POST['email']. '<br>Company: ' .$_POST['company'].'<br>Position: ' .$_POST['position'].'<br>Current System Used: '.$_POST['system']. '<br>Message: ' .$_POST['msg'].'</h1>';

if (!$mail->send()) {

  $result="Something went wrong please try again.";

}
else{

  $result="Thanks ".$_POST['name']." sending your request. ";
}

}

?>
```

Comment: Both the version of PHPMailer you're using, and the version of PHP are extremely outdated, and your site is vulnerable to attack as a result. Upgrade both, now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is clear on your post.

You have a "no route to host", so, the problem are your web hosting have blocked you to connect to gmail servers.

Comment: So I use the yahoomail instead of gmail?

Comment: Check your provider rules, maybe they have authorized email providers list (and lock connections to other providers)